# ServerSocket not accepting Connection

Tags: java, android

I have the following code in JAVA to create Server Socket to listen for incoming connections :

```
public class ConnectOracle {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"; //

  String serverName = "10.11.201.84";
  String portNumber = "1521";
  String db = "XE";
  String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":"
    + db; // connectOracle is the data
  // source name
  String user = "ORAP"; // username of oracle database
  String pwd = "ORAP"; // password of oracle database
  Connection con = null;
  ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
  Socket socket = null;
  DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
  DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

  try {
   Class.forName(driver);// for loading the jdbc driver

   System.out.println("JDBC Driver loaded");

   con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);// for
                // establishing
   // connection
   // with database
   Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();

   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
   System.out.println("Listening :8888");

   while (true) {
    try {

     socket = serverSocket.accept();
     System.out.println("Connection Created");
     dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(
       socket.getInputStream());
     dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
       socket.getOutputStream());
     System.out.println("ip: " + socket.getInetAddress());
     // System.out.println("message: " +
     // dataInputStream.readUTF());

     ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("select * from food_category");
     while(res.next()){
      System.out.println(res.getString(1));
     }

    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (dataInputStream != null) {
     try {
      dataInputStream.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

    if (dataOutputStream != null) {
     try {
      dataOutputStream.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

In my Android program I am trying to create a connection with this JAVA program . The code is as follows :

```
class ConnectToOracle extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

         Socket socket = null;
         DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
         DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ;
        }

        // Download Music File from Internet
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            try {
                 socket = new Socket("10.11.201.84", 8888);
                 dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                 dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                 dataOutputStream.writeUTF(textOut.getText().toString());
                 textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                if (socket != null){
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

            if (dataOutputStream != null){
                try {
                    dataOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

          if (dataInputStream != null){
              try {
                  dataInputStream.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
         }
            return null;

        }


        // Once Music File is downloaded
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // Dismiss the dialog after the Music file was downloaded

        }
    }
```

But the connection is not established . How can I establish connection ? Any advice is of great help .

Comment: show us the stack trace

Comment: I do not print anything in stacktrace .

Comment: When I run Java code it says JDBC Driver loaded
Listening :8888

Comment: is your server reachable via the device/emulator you are using to establish the connection? (network wise) make sure the port `8888` is opened on the server's firewall

Comment: My Phone is connected to the network . Any thing else I can do ?

Comment: yes, check server's firewall -if enabled- and make sure it has a rule to allow communication on `8888`

Comment: Firewall is off . How can I check that ?

Comment: if it's off, then it't not the issue, however to check any service if it's reachable, try to 1) `telnet` that **IP PORT** and see if you can connect to it, try first to run telnet from the same server, if success try from other PC on the same network, based on this you can decide if your server's code is OK / network is reachable, ... etc, this is kind of troubleshooting then you will know which direction you need to dig further ;)

Comment: 'Connection is not established' is not a problem description. Either there was an exception or the program blocked for longer than your patience. Explain.